# How to merge cells using the PHP version of the Google Sheet API v4

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-sheets-api

I've succesfully set up my credentials and access following the Quickstart guide & the API v4 documentation.

Everything works great, I successfully tried to:

- Update the spreadsheet title
- Read/write values in each cell
- etc.

However I keep getting the following error while trying to merge some cells:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: { "error": { "code":
>   400, "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name
>   \"merge_type\" at 'requests': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload
>   received. Unknown name \"range\" at 'requests': Cannot find field.",
>   "errors": [ { "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name
>   \"merge_type\" at 'requests': Cannot find field.\nInvalid JSON payload
>   received. Unknown name \"range\" at 'requests': Cannot find field.",
>   "domain": "global", "reason": "badRequest" } ], "status":
>   "INVALID_ARGUMENT" } }

Source code:

```
<?php

include_once(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php');
include_once(__DIR__.'/client.php');

$id_spreadsheet = '12xymzMe8OLbX9vw84'; // My spreadsheet ID (redacted for Stackoverflow)

/* Retrieve the API access */
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets(getClient());

/* Merge header columns */
$range = new Google_Service_Sheets_GridRange();
$range->setStartRowIndex(0);
$range->setEndRowIndex(1);
$range->setStartColumnIndex(1);
$range->setEndColumnIndex(24);
$range->setSheetId(0);

$request = new Google_Service_Sheets_MergeCellsRequest();
$request->setMergeType('MERGE_COLUMNS');
$request->setRange($range);

$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(['requests' => $request]);
$response = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($id_spreadsheet, $batchUpdateRequest);
echo '<pre>', var_export($response, true), '</pre>', "\n";
```

Comment: There is a documentation that explains how you can use the [`MergeCellsRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#mergecellsrequest) function. It was also explained in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498024/how-to-merge-cells-with-google-sheets-api/43501914), although it was written in python. But there it was explained how you can use the function.

Comment: Thank you. I've carefully read the documentation and examples as well as the post you mentioned before posting here. Unfortunately, the Python & PHP API libraries provided by Google don't work the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've not resolved this issue, the problem is in the request you are sending,
try to set your request in `Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest` `setRequests` method

```
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest();
$batchUpdateRequest->setRequests($request);
$response = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($id_spreadsheet, $batchUpdateRequest);
echo '<pre>', var_export($response, true), '</pre>', "\n";
```